# Android Landscape Orientation on Fragment Resetting Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-sensors

I am using shared preferences to keep track of a Admin code that is saved on the device, I have noticed that when I go this particular fragment that has a landscape orientation the preference gets called twice and on the second time it resets to its initial null value. this is the only fragment it happens on and i have been able to narrow it down to the line

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

is there a particular correct method to have shared preferences working with a landscape orientation

Here is the Code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Activity activity = getActivity();

        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean Admin_Mode = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("AdminCode", false);
        String IPaddress = sharedpreferences.getString("IP Address", "");

        System.out.println(IPaddress);
        System.out.println(Admin_Mode);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.augmented_reality_view, container, false);

        ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)activity).getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.hide();

        System.out.println("here");


        activity.setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mRotationVectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
        mMagneticSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);


        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationVectorSensor, 10000);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagneticSensor, 10000);

        HeadTracker = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.HeadTracker);


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (HeadTracker.isChecked() == true) {

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {

                SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
                        mRotationMatrix, event.values);

                if (mRotationMatrix[2] >= 0.6 && mRotationMatrix[0] >= -0.1 && mRotationMatrix[0] <= 0.2){

                    Left = true;
                    Right = false;

                }
                else if (mRotationMatrix[2] <= -0.8 && mRotationMatrix[0] >= -0.1 && mRotationMatrix[0] <= 0.2){

                    Left = false;
                    Right = true;
                }
                else{
                    Left = false;
                    Right = false;;
                }

            }

        }

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

            if(event.values[2] >= 390){
                MagnetButtonPressed = true;
            }
            else{
                MagnetButtonPressed = false;
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
```

Any Advice would be Epic :)

Cheers

Steve

///...... EDIT .........\\\
added in settings fragment code

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceFragment {

public SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

String IPaddress;
int PortNumber;
Boolean Admin_Mode;


public Settings() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);

    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    final SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    IPaddress = sharedpreferences.getString("IP Address","");
    PortNumber = sharedpreferences.getInt("Port Numner", 1);
    Admin_Mode = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("AdminCode", false);

    final EditText mEdit   = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ipaddress);
    final EditText mEdit2   = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.portnumber);
    final EditText AdminCommandBox = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.AdminCommandBox);

    mEdit.setText(IPaddress);
    String strI = Integer.toString(PortNumber);
    mEdit2.setText(strI);


    Button clickButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Update_Settings);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("IP Address", mEdit.getText().toString());
            editor.putInt("Port Numner", Integer.parseInt(mEdit2.getText().toString()));
            editor.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Port and Ip Updated!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    final Button Authorise = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Authorise_Button);

    if (Admin_Mode == false){Authorise.setText("Authorise");}
    else if (Admin_Mode == true){Authorise.setText("Deactivate");}

    Authorise.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Admin_Mode == false){

                if (AdminCommandBox.getText().toString().equals("FerasQUT123")) {

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("AdminCode", true);
                    editor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Code Authorised",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Authorise.setText("Deactivate");

                }

                else{

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Enter the Correct Code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }
            else if (Admin_Mode == true){

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("AdminCode", false);
                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity()," Deactivated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Authorise.setText("Authorise");

            }


        }
    });


    return rootView;
}



public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}}
```

Comment: Where does the preference in question get set? Reading a preference can't change it's value. I'm guessing something is happening in between reads.

Comment: @Jonathan727 -The preference gets set in another fragment, this is the only one that has a issue, all the others work perfectly but don't use landscape orientation. I have a feeling it's to do with the get application context in setting the orientation. If I remove the line for orientation it works as it should but I need that fragment to be in landscape

Comment: Does it happen if the orientation of the device is already portrait?

Comment: @Jonathan727 - nope it only happens when the device is in landscape mode

Comment: It sounds like it is a side effect of your activity being destroyed and recreated in landscape mode.

Comment: Could you post that fragment that sets that preference?

Comment: @Jonathan727 - Added, its sets it correctly and works properly i is just something to do with the landscape orientation. using System.out.println that LogCat shows that it has the orginal value when the fragment starts but then right away it does the same thing again but reverts to the old values

Comment: could it be that you call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` inside of `onCreateView`

Comment: @Jonathan727 - Nope doesn't seem to be it, I think for some reason the Layout orientation is causing the fragment to be reloaded straight away again

Comment: A few more questions: 1.) Have you factored in the fact that `onCreateView` will not be called after screen rotation? (however `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onActivityCreated` will)  2.) How are you determining that *Admin_Mode* has changed; `System.out.println(Admin_Mode);`? 3.) Is there any place in your app that you call `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues`??? If so, where?

Comment: @Jonathan727 - 1.) Yeah, I need that fragment to be in landscape all the time while the rest of my fragments are needed to be portrait, so the orientation of the fragment doesn't change. 2.) in the shared preference i get the state of the admin mode at the beginning of the on create, i set it in the main activity to false and then update it in the settings fragment if the correct code is entered. 3.) no i do not call PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the shared preference i get the state of the admin mode at the beginning of the on create, i set it in the main activity to false and then update it in the settings fragment if the correct code is entered.

Your issue is that you are setting admin mode to *false* in the activity's `onCreate` method. When the screen orientation changes, the activity will be destroyed and recreated--so `onCreate` will be called again, which is setting your admin mode preference to false.

Comment: @user3774031 Glad you found this helpful. As an alternative to setting admin mode to *false* in `onCreate`, I was thinking what you might do is add a *logout* menu item that changes this preference when the user explicitly selects it. You could also add an expiration time to another preference when the user authenticates so that if they don't explicitly log out, their login will still expire.